# React Bootstrap Sticky Navbar which slides down after scrolling past header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

The snippet below is almost an example of what I want (click "**Run Code Snippet**")

```js
class TopBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={isHide:false};
      this.hideBar = this.hideBar.bind(this)
    }
    hideBar(){
       let {isHide} = this.state
       window.scrollY > this.prev?
       !isHide && this.setState({isHide:true})
       :
       isHide && this.setState({isHide:false})

       this.prev = window.scrollY;
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        window.addEventListener('scroll',this.hideBar);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
         window.removeEventListener('scroll',this.hideBar);
    }
    render(){

        let classHide=this.state.isHide?"hide":""
        return <div className={"topbar "+classHide}>topbar</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TopBar/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.topbar{
  position: fixed;
  height:40px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:22px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition:top .3s;
}

.hide{

  top:-40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
  <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
    <br><br><br>
  
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus culpa nostrum explicabo modi magni suscipit ipsam ducimus non iste. Iste quam quaerat doloremque aliquam commodi architecto qui voluptates laboriosam, fuga?
```

In this snippet the navbar dissappears after scrolling down. I want the navbar to appear after scrolling past a website header, in the same manner that the navbar does in this snippet

I want to be able to do this

- using **Bootstrap** and **React**,
- have the NavBar be **invisible at first**,
- and have it **slide onto the screen fixed at the top after scrolling past the header**
- using as little custom css as possible

It should look like the stackoverflow navbar essentiallly, but would only be visible once scrolling past a header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the answer from Akber (which has a full edit queue) but this one fits the condition that the NavBar slides in and out, and lets you assign a shadow to the Navbar. The line of importance for removing or adding the NavBar based on page position is `const pos = window.pageYOffset;`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './style.css'

const TopBar = () => {
  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = useState(false);

  const hideBar = () => {
    const pos = window.pageYOffset;
    pos > 120 ? setIsHidden(true) : setIsHidden(false) 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", hideBar, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", hideBar);
    };
  }, []);

  let classHide=isHidden?"hide":""
  return <div className={`topbar ${classHide}`}>topbar</div>;
}

export default TopBar
```

**CSS**

```
.topbar{
  position: fixed;
  height:40px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:22px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition:top .3s;
}

.hide{

  top:-40px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to

- add a listener for the scroll event, and toggle the "flag-for-navigation-visibility" when it goes past the header (height 120px for example);
- Next toggle the correct class based on the "flag-for-navigation-visibility"

relevant **CSS**:

```
.showBar{display:block}
.hideBar{display:none;}
```

relevant **Component**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const TopBar = () => {
  const [barVisibility, setBarVisibility] = useState(false);
  const [scrollPosition, setSrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    position >= 120 ? setBarVisibility(true) : setBarVisibility(false);
    setSrollPosition(position);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, { passive: true });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="topBar" className={barVisibility ? "showBar" : "hideBar"}>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light fixed-top">
        <h1>This is the top bar...</h1>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopBar;
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-so65tq)

Comment: thanks, do you know how to make it slide on and off the screen instead of just appearing?

Comment: Also I'm trying to give it a shadow, and for whatever reason no shadows are showing up

Comment: This actually isn't really an improvement over what I already had posted, I already had something that did this more or less, but there were some conditions that it didn't meet, and this didn't really fix them other than setting a page position to be condition instead of the scroll direction